# Como hacer una consulta de una fila por bloques en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo 1000 datos y quiero hacer una consulta que me muestre los primeros 50 datos y al terminar de usarlos, me realice nuevamente la consulta de los siguientes 50 datos

Ejemplo:
En el select deben mostrar los primeros 50:
1
2
3
....
48
49
50
Después los siguientes 50 
51
52
... 
99
100
Y así sucesivamente hasta terminar todos los datos en la tabla.
No sé si se pueda realizar esto con un top, gracias

Saludos,

Comment: Quieres hacer un paginador? esto sera en WEB,Una aplicacion de escritorio o como piensas hacerlo. Y que versión de SQL Server tienes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En SQL Server tienes una función `OFFSET` de [paginación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/gg699618(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Obtenemos los 50 primeros registros

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla 
ORDER BY id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

Equivalente a

```
SELECT top 50 * 
FROM Tabla
```

Obtenemos los 50 segundos registros (del 51 al 100)

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla 
ORDER BY id OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

Obtenemos todos los registros evitando los 50 primeros

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla
ORDER BY id OFFSET 50 ROWS
```